# Deleting CoreData objects causes FetchedResultsController to error

Tags: ios, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using the Big Nerd Ranch `BNRCoreDataStack`, but I suspect that this problem would exist if I was using standard `CoreData`.

I have a `FetchedResultsController` to populate my table by fetching NSManagedObjects. These are being rendered in sections and rows. My problem is that when I delete my `NSManagedObjects` elsewhere, I get an error from the `FetchedResultsController`:

```
[error] error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 0 into section 1, but there are only 1 sections after the update with userInfo (null)
```

This leaves my cells visible in the table afterwards, and when I tap on one I get this error:

```
fatal error: Index out of range
```

So, this tells me that the `FetchedResultsController` has failed to remove the cells from my table when I deleted the CoreData objects.

What is strange is that I am reloading the table data on `viewWillAppear` so I would assume that that would clear the table. How can I force the `FetchedResultsController` to dump all knowledge of the data and start from scratch?

Comment: You need to implement the FetchedResultController's delegate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24983544/589224

Comment: I have. I believe this is where the problem originates: An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent

Comment: I think this is because of the sorting of sections based on my object property.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. My managed object is a Note class. Here it is:

```
@objc(Note)
class Note: NSManagedObject {

    @nonobjc override class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest{
        return NSFetchRequest(entityName: "Note");
    }

    @NSManaged var title: String?
    @NSManaged var body: String?
    @NSManaged var day: CalendarDay?
    @NSManaged var timestamp: NSDate?
}

extension Note: CoreDataModelable {

    static var entityName: String {

        return "Note"
    }

    var sectionTitle:String {

        willAccessValueForKey("day")
        defer { didAccessValueForKey("day") }

        if day != nil {

            return day!.timestampString!

        }else{
            return "___"
        }
    }
}
```

Notice I have this extra variable called `sectionTitle` ? Well, my `FetchedResultsController` was using that as its Section sorting key. The exception was happening when it tried to access the `Day` object, which had already been deleted.

The lesson learnt here, is not to try and add variables like this into your managed object classes, but make sure you have a managed attribute of your entity that you can use for sorting. It's managed for a good reason.